# Como atualizar o CakePHP da versão 0.2.9 para a versão mais recente, com segurança

Tags: php, cakephp

Eu peguei um site para administrar que é um gerenciador de conteúdo que foi desenvolvido em `CakePHP` na versão **0.2.9**.

Gostaria de saber qual é a forma correta e mais segura para atualizar para a versão **2.0** ou para a **3.0**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente não há nenhum guia de migração da versão 0.2.9 disponível no site da `cakephp` além disto é possível que você tenha que modificar bastante coisa sabendo que houveram migrações do 1.2 para 1.3 depois para 2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3... até 3.0 então se você for verificar o que mudou em cada versão migrada compensa mais pegar a versão 3 e refazer o projeto, em resumo você pode escolher duas ações, verificar todas as versões migradas pelas modificações, ou pegar a ultima versão e fazer com base nela.

[Lista de Migrações na v2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices.html)

[Lista de Migrações na v3.0](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices.html)

Comment: Obrigado @Gabriel.